# Vertical Scroll Bars in specific DIV containers only

Tags: html, css, vertical-scrolling

I'm building a page that has a list on the left, and a container showing a single item's details on the right. Here is a sample image showing the page layout and the parts I want to scroll.

[image]

In both the left container and the right container, I need to scroll when the data exceeds the container's viewport height. I only want the red-highlighted containers to scroll--the outer blue container is fixed, and the yellow portion inside the blue container is fixed. Only the red containers' contents should scroll, only when applicable.

I've put up a [codepen](http://cdpn.io/vaouE) where I'm playing around with it and can share it with you (the app itself is behind firewall, codepen is the best I can do). What you'll see on the codepen is that I can get the container to scroll when I set it's height (in this case, 380px, which is loosely about how much space is there on screen). If you move the sample codepen's container up, you'll see the scroll area stays fixed (duh), and if you increase the height of the scrollable container beyond 380px, once you go below viewport, scrolling starts to go away--at around 800px or so it completely goes away.

What the heck am I missing here?  The blue containers should size themselves to the bottom of the viewport, whether it's 800px high or 1600px high. Then The red container's height would fill that available height inside the blue container, and scroll if necessary.

I'm really stumped on what I'm missing here.

**Edit**: jQuery and javascript sizing are not options. This is achievable by CSS only, I'm just missing some property somewhere and am stumped.

**Edit 2**: I tried the suggested html (html: height:100%, etc). It works in codepen, but when I attempt it on my full version of the site, it doesn't work. In the screenshot here, you can see the blue high-lighted area is the scroll container in question, and the white bar on the right is the scrollbar (custom-styled background) but no actual scroll--just the bar background.
[image]

Comment: Is that real personal information?

Comment: Oh hellz no. All dummy data.

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented a basic version which should help you out.

You can find the code over at https://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/aWmMeJ .

Here is the CSS

```
body,
html {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebar {
  width: 20%;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.content {
  background: yellow;
  color: brown;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with css just use overflow-y:scroll and define the max height, or just height

```
.that-box {
    overflow-y:scroll;
    height: ###px;
}
```

--edit: and hide the scroll bar at a certain width

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) 
{
    .that-box {
        overflow-y:hidden; //this will cause clipping on content outside of the box
        height: ###px;
    }
}
```

--edit2: a CSS solution

```
html {
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative }
body {
    height:100%}
.box {
    position:fixed;
    height:100%;}
```

Comment: IMO the best way to do that, but I think he wants to use a custom scrollbar too.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it doesn't address the height adjustment part of my question, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I might have misunderstood; are you also asking how to make the height of the box always fill up the page too?

Comment: Oh you mean hide the scroll bar at a certain height! ill edit my example.

Comment: So I have a fixed customer base. We only support chrome. But the outlier is viewport height--some might have 1000px, some might have 1200px, some might have 800px browser viewport height. So yeah, I want that outer 'blue' container to fill available height, and then only scroll that inner red container when its contents exceed blue container height.

Comment: this bit of jquery will set a element to the window 
$('.thebox').height($(document).height());

Comment: Do you mean at a certain height? I'm not sure why you introduced width into the equation. And I only ever want to hide the scrollbar if the content inside the red container is less than would fill viewport height. So in the above screenshot, if only Janet Butler's object were present, it wouldn't need to scroll.

Comment: jQuery isn't an option.

Comment: media queries get a viewports width, its associated heights of common resolutions.

Comment: ok... well this might not work depending on other css things you may be doing. I'll edit my answer further.

Comment: Mat, see updated original post for results. What you proposed worked in codepen but not actual site code.

Comment: There is just so much convoluted CSS going on in that codepen its a really poor example, because isolating the one class you do need to change is very difficult. Honestly I would suggest taking the time to work back from the basics. Everyone and awhile I't doesn't hurt to start over knowing a little more. Uh, and having like 10 nested CSS classes is your problem. No one can properly manage inheritance that nested.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I like to use is through use of the view width (vw) and view height (vh) units. Using 100 respectively for each is the equivalent of your viewport's current size.

---

### HTML

```
<div class="dashboard">
   <div class="left-panel v-scroll">
      <!-- the stuff on your left nav -->
   </div>

   <div class="right-panel v-scroll">
      <!-- the stuff on your right nav -->
   </div>
 </div>
```

### CSS

```
.dashboard{
  width: 100vw;
}

.left-panel{
  height:100vh;
  width: 20%;  
  float:left;  
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.right-panel{
 height:100vh;
 width: 76%;
 display: flex;
}

.v-scroll{
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

This will ensure that they will scale according to how your screen size changes.